Multiplicity of the numbers less than 100
I've done a lot of AMC 10/AIME questions previously, and amidst them I find some sort of similar to this form:
Person x has chosen a number from 1 to 100. Person y is attempting to guess it. Person y can ask questions that person x has to answer which can help narrow down the value of the number person x chose.
Person y's questions:
Q1, Q2, ..., Qn (where n is a positive integer)
Based on this, person y determines the answer.

This has led me to ask the following question:

Question: Suppose person A has chosen a number from 1 to 100. Person B is attempting to guess that number. To help narrow down the value of the number person A chose, person B is allowed to ask questions of the form "is your number a multiple of n?" where n is a positive integer greater than 1. Given this, is there a minimum number z of questions person B has to ask such that person B is guaranteed to determine the value of person A's number? Note that person A can only choose positive integers between 1 and 100.

EDIT: It appears with prime numbers, the solution to this question was easier than I thought. However, it has inspired another question to ask, which I'll post on another thread.

$\log_2(10) = 7$ using Bisection?

Sorry, could you perhaps explain this solution in more detail? I'm a bit unfamiliar with bisections.
edit: Additionally, this appears to be more complicated than it looks. One would probably think (what I thought) Is it a multiple of: 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,etc? But if the number is 97, it would take a long time to get there.

@goldboy Seems unlikely that you can always bisect. In the first step you can ask about multiples of 2. if the answer is no, then the next best that you can do is a $\frac{1}{3} - \frac{2}{3}$ split.

The hardest case is actually if the chosen number is $1$, since the only way to conclude it is $1$ is by asking "is your number a multiple of $p$" for all $25$ primes $p$ less than 100.

You don't need straight bisection to minimuze questions in the more general case. If you know powers of $2$ and can calculate additions with them, then "is it less than 64?" gives the first of seven bits, "is it less than 32/96?" gives the next bit, etc.

Since your first question already has an accepted answer, I suggest that you create a new post for your second question.

alright, apparently the second one is much more complex than this one, heh. :)

There are $25$ primes from $1$ to $100$. For each prime $p$, the only question that will get a "yes" answer is, "Is your number a multiple of $p$?" Also, person B can choose $1$, which will never get a "yes" answer for any question.
Therefore, with fewer than $25$ guesses, if A answers "no" to every question, then this is consistent with at least two numbers: $1$, and any unguessed prime. This shows that at least $25$ guesses are necessary.
(Note, though, that the strategy of guessing all $25$ primes will not work out! This fails to distinguish, for example, $4$ from $8$.)

Here is a strategy that finds the answer in 25 guesses or fewer.

B begins by asking, "Is your number a multiple of $n$?" for $n=2, 3, 5, 7, 11$.
B makes a list of all the numbers from 1 to 100 which are consistent with A's answers to these five questions. Let $a_1 < a_2 < \dots < a_k$ be these numbers.
B continues by asking, "Is your number a multiple of $a_k$?" then "Is your number a multiple of $a_{k-1}$?" and so on. If the answer to "Is your number a multiple of $a_i$?" is "Yes", then A's number is $a_i$. If the answer to the first $k-1$ of these questions is no, then A's number is $a_1$.

The logic in step 3 is that when $n$ is the highest remaining valid option, if A answers "yes" to "Is your number a multiple of $n$", the number can only be $n$ itself. If A answers "no", then $n$ is definitely ruled out.
The goal of the first five questions is to reduce the number of questions needed in the second phase. How well does this go? Well, there are two main cases:

A could answer "no" five times, leaving 1, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97 as the possibilities.
A could answer "yes" then "no" four times, leaving 2, 4, 8, 16, 26, 32, 34, 38, 46, 52, 58, 62, 64, 68, 74, 76, 82, 86, 92, 94 as the possibilities.

The first case leaves $k=21$ possibilities, and the second case leaves $k=20$ possibilities. All other cases can be checked to leave even fewer possibilities.
The total number of guesses the strategy need is $5 + (k-1)$, which is always at most $5 + (21 -1 ) = 25$. This shows that $25$ guesses are sufficient.

Here is a second, more systematic strategy for B. Go through the primes in increasing order. For each prime, ask:

"Is your number a multiple of $p$?"
"Is your number a multiple of $p^2$?"
"Is your number a multiple of $p^3$?"
...

until the first "no" answer, or until the power of $p$ exceeds $100$. Stop once there is only one number consistent with the given answers.
If A picks the number $a \in \{1,\dots,100\}$, how many questions will it take B to identify it? Well:

The number of "yes" answers A gives will be equal to the number of prime divisors of $a$, with multiplicity. For every prime power $p^k$ dividing $a$, if B did not get to asking about $p^k$, then B cannot distinguish $a$ from $a/p$.
The number of "no" answers A gives will be the number of primes $q$ that are either (1) less than the largest prime dividing $a$ (in which case B asks about them on the way to the last "yes" answer) or (2) less than $100/a$ (in which case B needs to hear a "no" about them to distinguish $a$ from $aq$).

Calculating the total number of questions for each number between $1$ and $100$, we can verify that here, too, no number requires more than $25$ guesses. The average number of guesses this strategy requires is $9.35$: an average of $2.39$ "yes" answers and an average of $6.96$ "no" answers.

Nice! I guess it's time to make this a bit more complicated: Assuming the number is from 2 to 100, what is the expected number of questions B asks until they can figure out the answer to the question (using the prime strategy)? I may edit my question to include this as well.

@MarcusZhang That's a significantly harder question. I doubt this is the optimal strategy to reduce the expected number of questions.

My strategy is almost certainly not optimal in the cases where it deviates from the "main line" of guessing the prime numbers! I just figured that it wasn't worth optimizing, since it wasn't going to exceed the worst case.

I have a question though, what if the number were something like 90? This strategy seems nice, but if it were multiples of powers, we would also be stuck. It appears in this case, guessing all the primes wouldn't be enough. We would probably need conditions, such as "given its a multiple of 2, is it a multiple of 4"? and so on. It appears 25 is correct, but the strategy would have to be modified a bit.

The point is that we don't stick to guessing all the primes. The second half of my answer is the part that actually describes a strategy! If the number is something like $90$, then after B's first five questions of 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, A's answers would be "Yes, Yes, Yes, No, No". This leaves only 30, 60, and 90 as the possibilities, so B will ask about 90, then 60, then 30 next. I will edit to make this more clear.
